# In IntelliJ, how do I set default environment variables for new test configurations?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

My JUnit tests require three environment variables to be set. It is infuriating to have to set these for each new test class.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Select `Run > Edit Configurations...`, open the `Defaults`(`Templates` since IDEA 2020) node in the left tree and select `JUnit`. Now add your environment variables in the main panel and click `Apply` or `OK`. From now on, those variables will be added to every new JUnit run configuration in your project.

[image]

Comment: This would be defaults for this project only?

Comment: @nevets1219 I just tested it - this seem to be only project defaults.

Comment: For version 2020 at least it's Templates instead of Defaults